# React Native - Android PullToRefresh ListView

Tags: android, listview, react-native

Does anyone know how to implement a listview refresher for android in React-Native?
I think this is a common problem a lot of people have.

There is [react-native-refreshable-listview](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-refreshable-listview) , but it does not support android.

Comment: Depending on how urgently you need this I was reading it's a high priority/favourite for components in v0.16

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this behavior by using the `PullToRefreshViewAndroid` (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pulltorefreshviewandroid.html#content) launched with React Native 0.16.

As mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4793, you might have to use `style={{flex: 1}}` on the `PullToRefreshView` to achieve the result you want, something like this:

```
<PullToRefreshViewAndroid
  refreshing={isRefreshing}
  onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <ListView
    ...listViewProps />
</PullToRefreshViewAndroid>
```

Then you should get the same behaviour as ReactNativeRefreshableListView gives you, but on Android.

Answer (score 0):

React-native has an out of the box solution for pull to refresh

```
<ListView
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
      }
      ...
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
/>
```

and elsewhere in your class, an onRefresh() function...

```
onRefresh() {
  this.setState({refreshing:true});
  //refresh data and set refreshing to false as appropriate for your app...
}
```